# Visiting other temples after visiting Sri Kalahasti Temple

Tags: belief, temple

Is it true that you are not supposed to visit other temples after visiting Sri Kalahasti Temple in India?

Comment: No there is no such restrictions. Is it just hearsay or you have got any reference ?

Comment: Well, I heard it from an uncle who went to India.